# Editor with design view?

Tags: html, editor, dreamweaver

There are editors better than dreamweaver in some cases but because most of them dont have html/code design view, i resort to dreamweaver.

Does anyone know any other code editor having design view like dreamweaver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a design view is somewhat pointless unless the design view is using a popular/modern rendering engine such as Webkit, Mozilla, Presto ( or whatever the newest Opera uses nowadays ) and such... last I recall the editor(s) that had them used outdated versions of the Opera rendering engine. Best case is if you just get a real efficient text editor such as `vim` and just alt tab to the browser and refresh, or use an online text editor and code inside the webpage itself.